# Filter array of objects by prop value uniqueness

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuejs2

Given this data structure:

```
const arr = [
  {
    name: "a",
    id: "1",
    vars: [
      { 
        sub_name: "aa", 
        sub_val: 32 
      }, 
      { 
        sub_name: "aa", 
        sub_val: 343 
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "b",
    id: "2",
    vars: [
      { 
        sub_name: "bb", 
        sub_val: 32333
      }, 
      { 
        sub_name: "bc", 
        sub_val: 34312
      }
  }
]
```

I'm trying to filter each `vars` property by the uniqueness of the `sub_name` to return this data structure:

```
const arr = [
  {
    name: "a",
    id: "1",
    vars: [
      { 
        sub_name: "aa", 
        sub_val: 32 
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "b",
    id: "2",
    vars: [
      { 
        sub_name: "bb", 
        sub_val: 32333
      }, 
      { 
        sub_name: "bc", 
        sub_val: 34312
      }
  }
]
```

My attempt here:

```
removeDuplicates (arr, prop) {
  return arr.filter((obj, i, a) => {
    return a.map(o => o[prop]).indexOf(obj[prop]) === i
  })
}

this.someArrayOfObjects.map(o => this.removeDuplicates(o.vars, "sub_name"))
```

Returns an array of arrays.

```
const arr = [
  [{
    name: "a",
    id: "1",
    vars: [
      { 
        sub_name: "aa", 
        sub_val: 32 
      }
    ]
  }],
  [{
    name: "b",
    id: "2",
    vars: [
      { 
        sub_name: "bb", 
        sub_val: 32333
      }, 
      { 
        sub_name: "bc", 
        sub_val: 34312
      }
  }]
]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss to spread the `...o` to return the rest of properties of the array.

```js
const arr = [ { name: "a", id: "1", vars: [ { sub_name: "aa", sub_val: 32, }, { sub_name: "aa", sub_val: 343, }, ], }, { name: "b", id: "2", vars: [ { sub_name: "bb", sub_val: 32333, }, { sub_name: "bc", sub_val: 34312, }, ], }, ];

function removeDuplicates(arr, prop) {
  return arr.filter((obj, i, a) => {
    return a.map(o => o[prop]).indexOf(obj[prop]) === i;
  });
}

const result = arr.map(o => ({
  ...o,
  vars: removeDuplicates(o.vars, "sub_name"),
}));

console.log(result);
```

If you want to do it in one function, you can use the function below.

```js
const arr = [ { name: "a", id: "1", vars: [ { sub_name: "aa", sub_val: 32, }, { sub_name: "aa", sub_val: 343, }, ], }, { name: "b", id: "2", vars: [ { sub_name: "bb", sub_val: 32333, }, { sub_name: "bc", sub_val: 34312, }, ], }, ];


function removeDuplicates2(arr, prop) {
  return arr.map(e => ({
    ...e,
    vars: e.vars.filter(
      (el, i, a) => i === a.findIndex(el2 => el[prop] === el2[prop])
    ),
  }));
}

const output = removeDuplicates2(arr, "sub_name");

console.log(output);
```

Comment: I found this the clearest for my purpose, and it used the ES6 spread operator to boot (since I asked about ES6). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code and it does not show the same output. However I made this one change and it works:

If you are modifying one property modify then return the object with the modified property:

```
console.log(arr.map(o => {  o.vars = removeDuplicates(o.vars, "sub_name");
                         return o;} ));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this when you are calling your removeDuplicates function.

```
const result = arr.map((a) => {
    a.vars = removeDuplicates(a.vars, 'sub_name')
    return a;
})
```